# Question on Absolute Continuity of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can I ask why does the question of absolute continuity of measure require the assumption of sigma-finiteness ?

Thanks!

Comment: What question are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. A measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to another measure $\mu$ if $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A) = 0$.

However, the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) doesn't hold if you remove the sigma-finiteness of the two measures [cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#The_assumption_of_.CF.83-finiteness)]. Note that there are generalizations that *weaken* the assumption of sigma-finiteness, but you can't simply remove this assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think i got the idea wrongly. However, in the wikipedia site it mentioned that $0=f(a)$ for all real numbers $a$. This implies that the function $f$, therefore the Lebesgue measure $\nu$ is zero, which is a contradiction. 

Would you mind explaining this part?

Comment: The integral of $f$ with respect to the counting measure over the set $A = \{a\}$ is just $f(a)$, while the Lebesgue-measure of a singleton is $0$. Therefore $0 = \lambda(\{a\}) = f(a)$.

Comment: I see now! 
Thank you very much!